# Delete previous all words

Tags: vim

I can, for example, delete two words using `2daw` or `d2aw`. This deletes the current and *next* words.

Is there a way to delete the current and *previous* words?

Answer (score 0):

assume your cursor is on the "current" word:

try:

```
dawb.
```

Comment: interesting. not scalable tho.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible natively. You can try this mapping, which handles counts:

```
noremap _d :<c-u>exe 'norm! vawo'.(v:count<2 ? '' : (v:count-1).'b').'d'<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal map

```
:nmap _d a<C-w><C-w><Esc>
```

On insert mode just press <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> twice two delete the previous two words
or <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> to delete all previous words

If you want to delete the whole line in normal mode you can use

```
cc ..................... start changing the whole line
dd ..................... delete current line and keep normal mode active
```